# Volley get pending requests by tag, is possible ?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have been worked on a scenario where depending on if a set of request have been successfully executed ex:

> TAG (s); "tag1", "tag2", "tag2"

Then perform a routine, if not successfully performed, for example, lost connection! another routine must be executed.

I know there is this method to cancel a set of request:

```
App.getInstance ().cancelPendingRequestsWithFilter (filter)
```

to cancel a tag specifies:

```
App.getInstance ().cancelPendingRequestsWithTag (tag)
```

Now, anyone know any way to check whether a given tag (one request), was completed or not? type:

```
App.getInstance ().getPendingRequestsWithTag(tag) // I know that this method does not exist in the default implementation but would like something along those lines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really find a method that does exactly what you're looking for, but you could develop a solution with existing methods by keeping a reference to your request, and checking the following two utility methods provided in the `Request<T>` class when needed:

```
/**
 * Returns true if this request has been canceled.
 */
public boolean isCanceled() {
    return mCanceled;
}


/**
 * Returns true if this request has had a response delivered for it.
 */
public boolean hasHadResponseDelivered() {
    return mResponseDelivered;
}
```

You could also just use custom `Listener<T>` and `ErrorListener`s to track your individual requests.